# How to explain the training process in restricted Boltzmann machine?

Tags: machine-learning

I'm studying about restricted Boltzmann machine (RBM) recently.

I have studied the paper by G. Hinton:
   https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~hinton/absps/guideTR.pdf

To train the image in the RBM is to "raise the probability" of the data of the network, but I can't explain why that make sense: how we train the network with a given image is to raise it's probability of the network

Can someone explain that? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about RBM as a black box which is able to generate things. Lets focus on the images domain - it is now a black box able to generate any kind of image - obviously most of the images do not represent anything, they are just plain noise. During training you are fitting internal parameters of RBM (which define how it generates things) in such a way, that a given set of training images has a high probability of being generated. In other words - you are changing parameters of RBM in such a way, that RBM starts to generate images of your choice. How can it be done in practise? Through optimization procedues. RBM is defined as a set of weights (thus constant number of floats, which interact in a specific manner), thus you can pose optimization problem

```
maximize_theta PRODUCT_x P(x | theta)
```

over your training samples x, where theta is set of your RBM weights. There are many ways of solving optimization problems, some use gradient approaches, some other, more specialized techniques. They all share the goal - to change initial theta (which is usually random) in such a way, that it behaves "a bit more in a way you desire". Thus, gradient based approaches will try to analitically compute which weights to change, to make your optimization criterion (here - probability) a bit higher. It does not "solve" the problem - it usually just iteratively gets closer and closer to actual solution.